# Activity summary showing actions with Community creation date

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, community-user, activity-summary

I just noticed that my Activity summary shows lines like

> created [tag] description

to the moment it was created by Community, instead of the moment I edited it.

I registered in Stackoverflow 16/1/2013 and some revisions appear as I did them on 2012 or even 2011. See [last page of my activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=all&page=445).

Examples:

- [str-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6559157/revisions) - Created Jul 2 '11 at 19:32 by Community.
- [include](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8897477/revisions) - Created Jan 17 '12 at 15:43 by Community.

Comment: This is a bug. Have a look at the link of [the first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8897477/1) of `include` tag wiki. It says: it is answered by you on *Jan 17 '12 at 15:43*.

Comment: Thanks @hims056, this adds consistency to the bug :)